# Disqualify lead in Dynamics CRM (iOS)

Tags: ios, dynamics-crm

How can i disqualify lead in Microsoft Dynamics CRM ? Is there any particular API for doing this from iOS platform?
I tried this :

```
for (id key in [details allKeys]) {

    if([key isEqualToString:@"LeadState"])
    {
        [contactPostDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"State"];
    }

    else if([key isEqualToString:@"LeadStatus"])
    {
        [contactPostDict setObject:@"6" forKey:@"Status"];
    }


}
```

This is the error:

```
"error": {
"code": "", "message": {
"lang": "en-US", "value": "Error processing request stream. The property name 'Status' specified for type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.Lead' is not valid."
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on the iOS platform but from the error that is being thrown, the error seems to be pretty straight forward.

You are looking for the keys "Status" & "State" but they don't exist. Instead you should be looking at their schema names which is as follows

> Status = statuscode, State = statecode

Can you try modifying the code to use the above keys and see if you still gets the same error.

Comment: "error": {
"code": "", "message": {
"lang": "en-US", "value": "Error processing request stream. The property name 'statuscode' specified for type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.Lead' is not valid."
}
}

Comment: Can you post the entire code here, especially the part where you are making the request message and posting it to CRM. There is definitely something wrong with you request message.

Comment: As its not letting me adding here,i have posted as an another answer.Can u plz check and let me know whats d error

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)setLeadStatus:(NSString *)ID andDetails:(NSMutableDictionary *)details
{
    NSString *uri =   [MSDYNAMICS_AUTHENTICATION_CALL stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LeadSet(guid'%@')/",ID]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]];
    
    request.HTTPMethod = @"MERGE";
    
    [request setValue:JSON_CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMETER forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:JSON_CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMETER forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    
    
    NSMutableDictionary *contactPostDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    

    for (id key in [details allKeys]) {
        
        if([key isEqualToString:@"LeadState"])
        {
            [contactPostDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"statecode"];
        }
        
        else if([key isEqualToString:@"LeadStatus"])
        {
            [contactPostDict setObject:@"6" forKey:@"statuscode"];
        }

        
    }
    
    NSError *err;
    
    NSData *postData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contactPostDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
    
    NSString* postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    //NSString *postString = @"";
    [request setValue:JSON_CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMETER forHTTPHeaderField:CONTENT_TYPE_PARAMETER];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
    
    
    SURLConnection  *conn = [[SURLConnection alloc] init];
    
    NSData *responseData  = [conn sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *err1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"error: %@",err1);
    
    if(responseData.length==0 && [conn.response statusCode] == 204)
    {
        
        [self getLeadDetailsForID:ID];
        return YES;
    }
    
    else{
        NSString *err = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"error: %@",err);
    }
    
    
    return NO;
}
```